# cant open xcode 4.5.1 app on jailbroken iphone 4s 5.1.1

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have created a simple app on xcode 4.5.1 and have followed a tutorial on how to send it over to my jailbroken iphone 4s (5.1.1). I've created a fake code sign and I have been able to transfer the app onto my iphone. But when I click on it to run it, it opens but immediately closes again. When I use the iphone as simulator on xcode it does the same thing and i get the error message "failed to get the task for process 27658".
Please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's simple:

I thing Xcode disallow this to reduce cracking code signing.
A developer program is needed. Thats all.

Take a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

If you're gonna write a succsessful app you should buy this.